# linux command sort -u is not working properly with chinese

Tags: linux, sorting, command, unique

In the text file, there's words line by line.

I need to remove duplicated words so I used linux command :

`sort -u a.txt > rm_dup.txt`

but the command `sort -u` seems to be wierd with chinesse character.

for example, there's 2 words-`昕动,昕锐`-and after the command, one of them disappeared.

Why the command recognize that these two words are same?

Comment: They don't disappear to me. Please make a reproducible example we can run (you don't have to post your entire `a.txt`, just a small part that still shows the problem)

Comment: oh, it's wierd. After your comment, I tried same test in other server, and nothing disappeared. but it's still disappear on that first one... It's concerned with some setting on the server?

Comment: Can you see what `LC_CTYPE`, `LC_COLLATE`, `LC_ALL` and `LANG` are on both servers? (e.g. `echo $LC_CTYPE`)

Comment: both server with problem(server1) & other server(server2):LC_CTYPE is empty, LC_COLLATE: C, and for server1, LC_ALL, LANG are same as  `ko_KR.UTF-8`. for server2, LC_ALL is empty, LANG is `ko_KR.utf8`

Comment: Hmm... I have no idea what else would affect `sort`

Comment: anyway thanks to you. at least, I know now it's not the command problem.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: oh, I didn't recognize that. Thanks to inform.